# How to bring 1/0 wire through foundation below grade?

Tags: electrical, subpanel, conduit

I’m building an off-grid cabin in California. I have an array of solar panels that feed into an inverter and batteries in a small utility shed, connected to a 150A main panel. I want to run 125A into a subpanel in the cabin, which is only a few feet away.

When they poured the foundation, the contractors ran a piece of 2” conduit in the side for electrical ingress. The conduit has what looks like two access points outside, but neither of them connect through - they only go a couple inches horizontally before hitting the wall of the vertical pipe.

That side of the cabin is on a slope, and my intention is to box that in with a retaining wall and fill it in, which would put both holes below grade. I could try to keep the upper hole above grade if I needed to.

If my calculation is correct, I need to run 1/0 aluminum wires in 1.5” conduit from the shed to the cabin. But how do I get it through these holes? It seems like the angle would make it hard to pull such thick wires.

Advice much appreciated!

[image: The guys who poured my foundation left two possible holes for electrical conduit ingress, using 2" PVC]
[image: The holes only go in an inch or two before hitting the side wall of the vertical embedded conduit.]
[image: This is the ground the conduit needs to travel]
[image: Here's the conduit coming up from the inside]

Comment: Any reason you don't enter the cabin the same way you enter the shed with a box above grade?  Then you have full control over the conduit and its bends, all entirely outside.  Those holes to nowhere look pretty useless.    Is the vertical pipe embedded in concrete or can you yank it out and get some kind of pullable bend down to where the hole is?

Comment: I could do a box above grade, I just figured they put this conduit in, maybe I should use it.  It is embedded in the concrete.

Comment: Box above grade is the better way to go. However if you insist on using the conduit, you need to run a pull chain through the pipe from inside and attach the wires. Make the connection to the chain  rounded with some tape.  A little silicone on the tape will allow the beginning of the wire to slide better.  Then pull the wire through rather than try to push.  Having someone outside guiding the wire as the one inside pulls makes for easier work.

Comment: I hope @RMDman doesn't perform colonoscopies. 

Comment: @Jay613, I would...but I'm not allowed.

Comment: Note, silicone lube, _not_ silicone caulking!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use a fitting saver in the horizontal opening to cut a hole in the side of the vertical pipe.  But it would be very difficult to pull 1/0 wires through that.  I don't have the experience or knowledge to say that it would be *impossible*, or that it would violate code, but I'll throw both those ideas out there for others to smack down.

The most sensible approach is to ignore the installed PVC and come up outside the building, exactly as you did on the shed, and transition to inside via boxes.

If you *really want* to come up through the foundation, and you want to come up inside the wall cavity where the vertical pipe currently is, I think the way to do it is to drill out that pipe, and cut a chase in the exterior of the foundation large enough to accommodate an appropriate sweeping PVC elbow positioned at the depth you want.  Whether it is ok to cut such a chase in this foundation at that location I do not know, and you should ask the engineer who designed the foundation.    If that sounds like a lot of work, I think running several 1/0 cables through a crudely sawn out 90 degree bend sounds worse to me, and you'll never know if you damaged the cables on the rough corner of the two pipes.

Comment: Yeah, I got a sweep and poked it into the hole to visualize and have pretty much come to the same conclusion.  There's no other way around that buried hard short angle.  I guess if I were only going with a 50A box it would be a different story.

Thank you for the thoughtful response.